# RDM LUN in MSCS - Maximum number of RDM that can be shared

Tags: exchange, vmware-esxi

We have a 3-node MSCS setup for Exchange 2007. I understand from V4 configuration maximums that we only have maximum of 4 IDE controllers for either Disk or CD-Rom.

We have used up all the IDE for Shared RDM LUM mapping to the Exchange servers i.e. IDE 0,1,2,3 have 144GB shared Raw lun mapped respectively.

We have a challenge to add additional storage group to this setup (mount additional shared RDM Lun) to help increase the number of storage group, but i seem not to have additional IDE and there's a requirement from this document as below:

"A separate virtual adapter must be used for clustered disks"

Please i need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've used IDE? I've only ever exposed RDM via a SCSI controller myself, have you tried that?